# How can I add multiple product in cart using vue js and django rest framework

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am trying to add multiple product in the cart. I am using vuejs and django rest framework. My problem is: When I add a product into the cart it added successfully But when I add another product it doesnt add. It adds the same product again and again.

For example:
I have three products named "A" and "B" and "C". I added "A". Then i try to add "C" in the cart. But it stills adds "A" in the cart. I cleared the session and tried again still add the "A" product if I try to add "C" product first. It always add "A" product.

Here is my store/index.js:

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'

export default createStore({
  state: {
    cart: {
      items: []
    },
    isAuthenticated: false,
    token: '',
    isLoading: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    initializeStore(state){
      if(localStorage.getItem('cart')){
        state.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'))
      }
      else{
          localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart))
      }
    },
    addToCart(state, item) {
      let exists = state.cart.items.filter(i => i.product.id === item.product.id)

      if (exists.length){
        exists[0].quantity = parseInt(exists[0].quantity) + parseInt(item.quantity)
      }
      else{
        state.cart.items.push(item)
      }
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(state.cart))
    }
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

Here is my add to cart page and code:

```
<template>
  <br />
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col1">
      <img v-bind:src="product.get_image" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
      <div class="product__title">
        <p>PRODUCT TITLE</p>
        <h2>{{ product.name }}</h2>
        <small>{{ product.short_description }}</small>
      </div>
      <div class="product__price">
        <p>Price: $ {{ product.price }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product__button">
        <input type="hidden" v-model="quantity" min="1">
        <button type="submit" class="button__primary" @click="addToCart">Add To Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

    import axios from 'axios'
    import {toast} from 'bulma-toast'
    
    export default {
      name: "ProductDetail",
      data () {
        return {
          product: {},
          quantity: 1
        }
      },
      mounted() {
        this.getProduct()
      },
      methods: {
        getProduct() {
          const categorySlug = this.$route.params.category_slug
          const productSlug = this.$route.params.product_slug
    
          axios.get(`/api/product-details/${categorySlug}/${productSlug}/`)
          .then(response => {
            this.product = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
          })
    
        },
    
        addToCart() {
            if(isNaN(this.quantity) || this.quantity < 1){
              this.quantity = 1
            }
    
            const item = {
              product: this.product,
              quantity: this.quantity
            }
            this.$store.commit("addToCart", item)
            toast({
              message: "Product has been added to cart" + item.product.name,
              type: "is-success",
              pauseOnHover: true,
              duration: 2000,
              position: "bottom-right",
              dismissible: true,
    
            })
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
    
    <style scoped>
      .col {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-gap: 5rem;
        height: 50vh;
        padding: 60px;
      }
      .col1 {
        height: 520px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .col1 img{
        object-fit: fill;
        height: 520px;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .col2 {
        display: grid;
        grid-auto-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 12px;
      }
    
      .product__button button{
        height: 40px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        background: #007bc4;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 3px;
      }
    
      .product__price p {
        color: #007bc4;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
    </style>
```

Here is the cartitem component:

```
<template>
  <tr class="is-fullwidth">
    <td>{{ item.product.name }}</td>
    <td>$ {{ item.product.price }}</td>
    <td>
      <button @click="increment(item)" class="plusButton">+</button>
        {{ item.quantity }}
      <button @click="decrement(item)" class="minusButton">-</button>
    </td>

    <td>{{ getTotal(item).toFixed(2) }}</td>
    <td><button class="delete"></button></td>
  </tr>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Cartitem",
  props: {
    initialItem: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      item: this.initialItem
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getTotal(item) {
      return item.quantity * item.product.price
    },
    increment(item){
      item.quantity += 1
      this.updateCart()
    },
    decrement(item) {
      item.quantity -= 1

      if(item.quantity === 0){
        this.$emit('removeFromCart', item)
      }

      this.updateCart()
    },
    updateCart() {
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.$store.state.cart))
    },

    removeFromCart(item) {
      this.$emit('removeFromCart', item)
      this.updateCart()
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .plusButton{
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
  .minusButton{
    border: none;
    background: #fff;
    font-size: 19px;
  }
</style>
```

I am new in vue js. I am trying to build this projetc so that i can learn. But this issue is eating my brain. I tried to use find function in sotre/index.js. It solved my problem though but if i clear the cookies and try to add product it gives me error.

is there any solution for me?

Thanks in advance.